# Return a vector free of duplicates [without using unique() or duplicate()]

Tags: r, loops, vector

I am trying to get rid of duplicates within a vector without using unique function (as this one doesn`t work in that instance).
My loop looks as follows:

```
#finding and deleting duplicates
dupes <- function(x) {
    for (i in 1:(length(x))){
        while (is_true(all.equal(x[i],x[i+1]))){
            x=x[-i]
        }    
            }
    print(x)
}
```

I want to run a vector through the function and get a vector (free of dupes) returned.

Comment: Please share [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: it might help if you explain *why* `unique()`  doesn't work in your case?

Comment: since you're using `all.equal()` I'm guessing that you're trying to remove *approximately duplicated* values, which is an interesting and challenging question ...

Comment: Hi Ben, the approximately duplicated paradox is probably what I am facing here... rounding also didnt help. However distinct() doesnt work as it seems to not be applicable for numerics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one simple way to do it -

```
# for numeric vector
x <- c(1:8, 4:10)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
x[ave(x, x, FUN = seq_along) == 1]
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

# for character vector
x <- as.character(iris$Species)
x[ave(x, x, FUN = seq_along) == 1]
# [1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"
```

Comment: Thanks Shree, that worked. Do you have an idea as to why that works and unique() or duplicate() don`t work? I am curious...

Comment: Please share the vector you are working with. Hard to comment without it.

Comment: Vector is numeric with rounded values (to the first decimal). Some are duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ways to do it, assuming that your vector is NOT numeric (i.e. It is integer or character),

```
set.seed(666)
v1 <- sample(15:20, 10, replace = TRUE)

as.integer(names(table(v1)))
#[1] 15 16 17 19 20
rle(sort(v1))$values
#[1] 15 16 17 19 20
```

Answer (score 0):

dplyr's `distinct()` function will work for you .

```
 library(dplyr)  
 df_new <- distinct(your_vector)
```